# Change order of divs using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, reverse

I have somthing like that:

```
<div>

   <div id = "a"/>
   <div id = "b"/>
   <div id = "c"/>
   <div id = "d"/>
   <div id = "e"/>
   <div id = "f"/>

</div>
```

And I want that in some cases it will be like that, and in some cases it will
extacly reversed:

```
<div>

   <div id = "f"/>
   <div id = "e"/>
   <div id = "d"/>
   <div id = "c"/>
   <div id = "b"/>
   <div id = "a"/>

</div>
```

I looking for some solution in javascript,
anyone have any idea.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You could use CSS rules to position your divs.

Comment: I tried loops and insertBefore but it's always work fine and I'm looking for something more aesthetic.

Comment: get the div's a float? Try float:left.. float:right.
Here you can try to change the float -> http://jsfiddle.net/0t5ertqz/

Comment: jQuery append(), .prepend(), after() and before() and some more can simply move your divs so you can reorder them.

Answer (score 2):

To sort jQuery elements you can simply use the `sort()` method:

```
$('#container div').sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.id < b.id ? -1 : 1;
}).appendTo('#container');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xv0apxfu/)

To change the order to ascending, reverse the `-1` and `1` in the ternary:

```
return a.id < b.id ? 1 : -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to sort elements. use `isReverse` to reverse sorting.

```js
function sort(arr, isReverse){
  
  arr.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.id > b.id) return  isReverse ? -1 : 1;
    if(a.id < b.id) return isReverse ? 1 : -1;
    return 0;
  });
  return arr;
}
var parent = $("#container");
var arr = sort(parent.children(), true);
arr.detach().appendTo(parent)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

   <div id = "a">a</div>
   <div id = "b">b</div>
   <div id = "c">c</div>
   <div id = "d">d</div>
   <div id = "e">e</div>
   <div id = "f">f</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it:
HTML

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

JS:

```
var divs = new Array("a","b","c","d","e","f");

var content = document.getElementById("content");
// Original
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(divs[i]));
    div.setAttribute("id", divs[i]);
    content.appendChild(div);
}

// Reverse
divs.reverse();
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(divs[i]));
    div.setAttribute("id", divs[i]);
    content.appendChild(div);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bigneo/jb20ad8m/